# Best way to use external functions (eg components that return nothing) in React redux app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to save some data into DB whenever the state (using Redux) changes.

```
//Save.js
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useEffect } from "react";

export const Save = () => {
    const destination = useSelector((configureStore) =>
        configureStore.locations.destination
    )
    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log("destination has been edited")
        //save into DB
    }, [destination])
    return(<>  
    </>)
}
```

The only way I can call this function is by rendering it in index.js like:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <CookiesProvider>

      <Provider store={store}>
        <Save/>
        <App />
      </Provider>

    </CookiesProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Everything works fine and as expected but I want to know if this is the best approach. I tried searching for best practices for what I'm trying to achieve, but Im still unsure. My approach just seems 'off' and im not sure if there is a 'react-y' way of doing it or some better alternative.

Comment: It kind of sounds like you are asking how to trigger a redux thunk when some other action occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to save some data into DB whenever the state (using Redux) changes.

You could do this with redux [`listenerMiddleware`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createListenerMiddleware) to dispatch an [`asyncThunk`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#createasyncthunk) to save your edited *Destination* to the db some time after the editing has stopped.

[Example](https://yy0kyt.csb.app/)

```
const listenerMiddleware = createListenerMiddleware();

listenerMiddleware.startListening({
  actionCreator: actions.edit,
  effect: async (action, listenerApi) => {
    listenerApi.cancelActiveListeners();
    await listenerApi.delay(1000);
    listenerApi.dispatch(saveDestination({ ...action }));
  }
});
```

---

This helps to keep your react component fairly presentational.

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { actions } from "./destinationSlice";

export const Destination = () => {
  const { edit, data, loading } = useSelector((state) => state.destination);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  return (
    <>
      <label>
        edit destination:
        <input
          value={edit}
          onChange={(e) => dispatch(actions.edit(e.currentTarget.value))}
        />
      </label>
      <label>
        saved destination:
        <input value={data} readOnly />
      </label>
      {loading && <p>saving</p>}
    </>
  );
};
```

---

The redux slice looks pretty simple here, too. Another benefit is that all your state remains in the redux slice, instead of being spread between redux, a react component and a react custom hook.

```
export const slice = createSlice({
  name: "destination",
  initialState: {
    loading: false,
    edit: "",
    data: ""
  },
  reducers: {
    edit: (state, { payload }) => {
      state.edit = payload;
    }
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(saveDestination.pending, (state) => {
      state.loading = true;
    });
    builder.addCase(saveDestination.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
      state.data = payload;
      state.loading = false;
    });
    builder.addCase(saveDestination.rejected, (state) => {
      state.loading = false;
    });
  }
});
```

---

In this example, the thunk is just returning a resolved promise after one second. But here you could call your `saveDestination` api however you like.

```
export const saveDestination = createAsyncThunk(
  "destination/save",
  async ({ payload }) => {
    await wait(1000);
    return Promise.resolve(payload);
  }
);

function wait(milliseconds) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds));
}
```

[image: Edit react rtk react toolkit listener middleware]

Comment: im not too familiar with thunks yet, but if this allows me separate concerns better, then ill definitely look into this. thank you for mentioning this!

Comment: I've added the thunk into the answer.

Comment: now that i learned more about async thunks. this is my preferred method for my problem. but i was just wondering why i need to use "builders"  . can i just do this ? `extraReducers:{ [saveDestination.pending]: (state) =>{state.isLoading = true},
`

Comment: Take a look at the react toolkit docs. There are a few different ways to write a reducer. In my experience, the builder notation seemed to work better for me within a typescript project.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is a custom hook, not a component.  That would be the more "react-y" way to do it.

Custom hooks are functions that return objects, functions, or state, or nothing at all, but are allowed to use React hooks in them.

A refactor into a custom hook might look like this:

```
import { useEffect } from "react";

export const useSave = (destination) => {

  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log("destination has been edited")
    //save into DB
  }, [destination])

}
```

With this approach you would pass in `destination` from your component that uses it.  Call it just like a function at the top of your component and pass in arguments.

So for instance, in your `App`:

```
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import useSave from "./filepath/useSave.js"

const App = () => {
  const destination = useSelector((configureStore) =>      
    configureStore.locations.destination
  )

  useSave(destination)

  return (<></>)
}
```

React is looking for the `use` keyword at the beginning of the function, that's how it knows it's a custom hook, and won't throw an error trying to use a React hook inside it.

##### Further

The return from the custom hook is very powerful, and can be used to return a function that dispatches to a reducer, or a valuable piece of state.

You would assign your hook to a variable and make use of it in your component.

Ex:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { setSomeState } from "path/to/reducer.js"

export const useSave = (destination) => {
  const [saving, setSaving] = useState(false)

  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log("destination has been edited")
    setSaving(true)
    //save into DB
    setSaving(false)
  }, [destination])

  const updateStore = (state) => {
    dispatch(setSomeState(state))
  }

  return { saving, updateStore }
}
```

Then in your component:

```
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import useSave from "./filepath/useSave.js"

const App = () => {
  const destination = useSelector((configureStore) =>      
    configureStore.locations.destination
  )

  const { saving, updateStore } = useSave(destination)

  return (
    <>
      {saving ? 
        <h1>Saving...</h1> 
        : 
        <button onClick={updateStore}>Set</button
      }
    </>
  )
}
```